# What is time consuming in Pandas .to_stata()?

Tags: pandas, stata

I have a Pandas df with 9 489 318 rows and 477 columns. The dtypes include timestamps, strings, booleans, integers and floats. There are missing values, and some column names might exceed 32 characters.

The export from pandas to a dta-file takes 1.5h using to_stata(). The same export to Feather takes 25 seconds. What dtypes are slow when exporting to Stata? Are there any other suggestions for making the export times more manageable?

I'm a scientist working with a group of fellow scientists, so I need to export data all the time from Pandas to Stata. Using Pyarrow to export to csv is and then opening the file in Stata is the fastest workaround that I've found, but that seems to handle the missing Timestamps in an undesired way.

Comment: You'd have to provide more details or a reproducible example... based on what you wrote timestamps could be the suspect, but can't be certain.